# Rotate image in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rotation

I'm trying to rotate my image, but not by 90 degrees or 180, I don't actually know the amount I want to rotate by. If I could get rotation to work, I'd just kinda do guess and check with the rotation amount, however I can't get the image to rotate. I've looked up numerous questions similar to this and they all use M_PI or something similar to that. I put that in my code and nothing happens, the image never rotates. Can someone please help me get the image to rotate.

```
Box6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"border.png"]];
Box6.center = CGPointMake(StickFigure.center.x + 22, StickFigure.center.y + 19);
Box6.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/45);
```

the M_PI/45 is not what I was using, I've just been messing around with numbers and nothing has been changing

Comment: Can you provide the code you use that should be performing the rotation?

Comment: @Aderis I added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` takes the angle in radians, as seen in [here in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/), so by passing `M_PI/45`, you are rotating a total of 2 degrees, which you might be mistaking for no rotation. To test if your code actually works I would put in just `M_PI`, which is equivalent to 180 degrees. If you are working in degrees and need the radians equivalent, use this formula: `radians = degrees * M_PI / 180`

Comment: ok thank you that's very helpful, just using M_PI, I wouldn't be able to see a difference because it's a symmetrical image. How would I rotate it, say, 45 degrees?

Comment: would I put
     
    Box6.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45 * M_PI/180);

Comment: It's not working, the box hasn't rotated at all and I put the exact line of code from my comment above

Comment: @karateman10998 Going out on a limb here. Instead of changing the view's transform property, you could try doing `view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleInRadians, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`. If that doesn't work, you can try calling [`self setNeedsDisplay];`. You are changing the transform matrix of the view, but it may not be getting used if the view has already been drawn. Doing `setNeedsDisplay` should fix this (if this is the issue).

Comment: ok so what would I type if I were using `CATransform3DMakeRotation`
sorry this is all kinda new to me

Comment: I typed this `Box6.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(45 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` still nothing :/

Comment: I edited my previous comment to have the code you need. The function works in axis-angle form, meaning that the first argument is how much you want to rotate in radians, and the last 3 parameters are the x, y, and z coordinates for a vector that represents the axis to rotate about. Since you are just doing 2D rotations, the x and y arguments will always be 0, and the z argument will always be 1.

Comment: @karateman10998 Remember to do `45 * M_PI / 180`. Also, have you tried the `setNeedsDisplay` yet?

Comment: oops forgot the `/180`
I don't know what setNeedsDisplay is or how to use it.... Let me try the 180 thing and get back to you

Comment: ok `45 * M_PI / 180` didn't work. How do I use `setNeedsDisplay`

Comment: @karateman10998 `[self setNeedsDisplay];` is a call that you perform on a `UIView` that makes it redraw itself. Basically it updates all the graphics for that view and its subviews. I have been looking through some of my old code that rotates views, and I can't find anything in it that you haven't tried, so if this doesn't work, I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: where would I put that, because all of the code I've been typing has been in the viewdidload

Comment: @karateman10998 you need to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the `UIView` that contains the `UIImageView` you are trying to rotate. Also make sure you are adding `Box6` to a view in the first place so that it actually is showing up.

Comment: box6 is added to the view how do i call setneedsdisplay on the uiview

Comment: Just try `[Box6 setNeedsDisplay];`, after this, I cannot help.

Comment: now it's saying no visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector setneedsdisplay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84316/discussion-between-karateman10998-and-aderis).